# Right now (mid-May 2021), are vaccinated travelers coming from a COVID "risk area" required to stay in quarantine when visiting Germany?

Tags: germany, covid-19, quarantine, vaccinations

I would like to visit Germany (departure from Romania, time ~ end of August) and I am trying to understand if I can do that without the need to stay in quarantine.

According to [Robert Koch Institut](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html) Romania is considered Risikogebiete (risk area). [This article](https://www.germany.info/us-en/-/2355466) mentions that risk area means when the infection incidence is more than 500 / 100K, thus the 14 days quarantine is required.

It is still not clear if this also applies to fully vaccinated persons. From an epidemiological point of view, requiring vaccinated persons to stay in quarantine does not make much sense since vaccinated persons are way less likely to get infected or infect someone else.

Comment: AFAIK rules differentiating between vaccinated and non-vaccinated travellers are in a state of flux, varying widely and subject to change at short notice. The EU has not yet announced anything officially for the whole bloc but some countries have communicated individual approaches https://www.cnbc.com/2021/04/30/places-where-vaccinated-people-can-travel-see-the-updated-list.html, Germany appears to be one of them https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus#content_3  However it is too early to say what might apply in August

Comment: @Traveller Depends what you mean by “the EU”. The Commission announced a lot of things, published a draft regulation and started efforts to roll out their [Digital Green certificate](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/covid-19-digital-green-certificates_en) in the coming month(s). Nothing is done until it's done but that's an admission that they won't be able to impose more specific rules to member states and a pretty detailed plan already.

Comment: Relevant details in the German corona regulations are currently changing almost on a weekly basis. The possibility to enter from a risk area and avoid a quarantine just by presenting an immediate negative test result was for example introduced on May 12th. It will be nearly impossible to predict which rules and processes you will have to adhere to if you are planning to travel in three months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way [the rules are structured](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/quarantaene-einreise/2371468#content_0), a quarantine is mandatory for everybody but it can be “shortened” once the German authorities have received a proof that you tested negative, are fully vaccinated, or recovered from Covid 19. The rules for so-called “variant areas” and “high-incidence areas” are slightly different. In any case, there is no blanket exemption from the quarantine requirement and the German authorities want to make that determination themselves.

The official definition of “vaccinated” is based on the recommendations of the [Paul-Ehrlich-Institut](https://www.pei.de/DE/arzneimittel/impfstoffe/covid-19/covid-19-node.html). You must have received all prescribed doses at least 14 days before travelling/ending your quarantine.

In practice, you still need to [register electronically](https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de/#/), go straight to your place of (temporary) residence but would presumably be allowed to go about your business as soon as you have provided a proof of vaccination. That also means you will need some sort of proof of vaccination in a language they accept (currently German, English, French, Italian, or Spanish).

Incidentally, the last regulation refers to some scientific justification for the rules. They suggests that vaccinated people are typically contagious for a shorter time if they get infected (rather than altogether non-contagious), hence a “reduced quarantine” even if it can feel like an exemption in all but name.

Comment: I have no problem registering electronically, but is it possible to register and have the registration processed before the actual trip? My visit is about 10 days and it makes no sense to go there just to have half of it lost due to quarantine.

Comment: @Alexei I don't think so but I haven't tried. The system was also introduced recently. I have the feeling most countries are striving for some predictability and are trying to establish more stable rules. So I don't share the general “anything is possible, we can't say anything about the future” mindset but I still think it's a bit early and things might get clearer by the end of the month.

Comment: Quarantine is necessary until a test or certificate of vaccination is uploaded to the site. This means that, if you upload the vaccination certificate before you arrive, quarantine lasts 0 days. Vaccinated persons do not need to do quarantine unless they come from a Virusvariantengebiet.